# Configuration - Is there a web based github concatenation tool?

Tags: javascript, github

I was told github has concatenation tool, rather I heard this at a tech event.

So if I have

```
file1.js
file2.js
...
```

It will concatenate them into

```
file_all.js
```

Is there a web interface for this? ( at www.github.com )

I want to be efficient and not copy paste this by hand.

I don't need anything complicated, just something that will do this automatically.

Comment: I don't think GitHub has this "built-in".

Comment: [`cat`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cat)?

Comment: There's about a zillion ways to concatenate files, you'll have to be more specific. Do you need this to be done as a build step? What build system if any? On-demand as the file is accessed in a webapp? (I use Grunt, but it's not exactly a simple tool.)

Comment: I strongly doubt GitHub has a way to change the contents of a repo after a commit is pushed. (Well, technically, post-receive hooks can do anything but it might not be easy. Look around in your repository settings if it's one of them?)

Comment: @livingston_mechanical It's not even clear what you want this tool to actually do - where should it grab the files from, where should it send them to? Or why should it be web-based if you already have the files in your project?Also, software recommendation questions aren't appropriate for SO anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/). It has become an extremely popular tool. It may take a little while for you to set it up but it was designed to automate tasks such as [uglifying](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify) (concatenating and minifying JS files).

Answer (score 1):

You want to automate your workflow? Go with maven and this package of tools for JS developers http://mojo.codehaus.org/javascript-maven-tools/